# Hibernate Tools - "version" column

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to generate the entites from my table using Hibernate Tools. I can do this successfully with one small gotcha.

Each of the tables (100+) have a column called "version" which is a timestamp. When I generate the entites I have get an attribute in the class called version (with accessor and mutator methods) which is good. However there is no annotation on the attribute such as
@Column(name="version"). I can script this into each of the java files but was wondering if there is a way to configure the tool to support this?

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`@Column(name="version")` is not necessary in this case because hibernate assumes that your column is named as it's field when no `@Column` annotation is present.